# Android NDK r4 san-angeles problem

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm starting to learn the android NDK and I've instantly come up against a problem.

I'e built the tool chain (which took a LOT longer than I was expecting!!) and I've compiled the C++ code with no problems and now I'm trying to build the java code.

Instantly I come up against a problem.  There is a file "main.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Hello World, DemoActivity"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

and I get the following errors:

```
Description Resource Path Location Type
error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_height' with value 'match_parent'). main.xml /DemoActivity/res/layout line 2 Android AAPT Problem
error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_height' with value 'match_parent'). main.xml /DemoActivity/res/layout line 2 Android AAPT Problem
error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_width' with value 'match_parent'). main.xml /DemoActivity/res/layout line 2 Android AAPT Problem
error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_width' with value 'match_parent'). main.xml /DemoActivity/res/layout line 7 Android AAPT Problem
error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_width' with value 'match_parent'). main.xml /DemoActivity/res/layout line 7 Android AAPT Problem
```

So I can see the problem lies in the fact that these "match_parent" strings are in there.  Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Removed the NDK tags. The question as it stands now has nothing to do with NDK or native development. Please consider changing the title accordingly!

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Check what [API Level](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html) you are using.

`FILL_PARENT` was renamed to `MATCH_PARENT` in API Level 8 (Android 2.2).

Comment: yeah I've just discovered that changing it to fill_parent solved the issue.  Strangely it is on api level 4 (which is what eclipse auto set it up as ... I assumed thats what the files were talling it .. may be wrong though!).  Cheers for the help! :)

Comment: I'm going through the introductory Notepadv2 exercise on the official Android Developers website; it would have been nice if they'd have mentioned that fact. But good to know, thanks!

Comment: when creating a new project in eclipse, and choosing `Android Sample Project` in the wizard, and then on to a `Google APIs` target of API 10 or older, the `Sample4Demos` that is created ends up containing a bunch of xml that refers to match_parent instead of fill_parent (amongst other problems).