# Hierarchical Parent Error when create new android project

Tags: android

When I create new android project, in "New blank activity", the wizard show an error 
`Activity name must be specified` as below:

[image]

What is this error? and Hierarchical parent used to be for what?
if I type a string in Hierarchical Parent (ex: "test") then the error disappear.

and What is `Error parsing XML: junk after document element`? this error appear in my layout xml file.

Comment: Always try to write your class name in capital letters.In your case write the name of your activity in capital letters (i.e. Main).

Comment: thank you but I have just tried this, but this red cross still there, error mention about "Activity Name" but the red cross locate at "Hierarchical Parent". I think the problem is "Hierarchical Parent".

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. The problem is Eclipse/Android Plugin.

You have to update Eclipse.

Go Eclipse-->Help-->Check for Updates

Comment: Had the same problem and updating fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

This may be the case of adt plugin problem.
[ReInstalling adt plugin](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html)
may fix this problem.But keep in mind while installing adt plugin always check on

> Contact all update sites during install to find required software

on eclipse