# Android application failed to run

Tags: android, eclipse, apk, facebook-android-sdk

My issue is that I never be able to run my android application in Emulator or in a real device.

I have eclipse Helios as

```
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

Version: Helios Service Release 2
Build id: 20110301-1815
(c) Copyright Eclipse contributors and others 2000, 2011.  All rights reserved.
Visit http://eclipse.org/

This product includes software developed by the
Apache Software Foundation http://apache.org/
```

Latest SDK and proper AVD are configured. But the issue is while creating an application. 
I follow these steps

```
1) File > New > Android Application Project
 Here a diaglog box appears where I put application name etc, The finish button is disabled in this step.

2)On clicking next the "Configure Launcher Icon" dialog appears, here too the finish button is disabled

3) In the third step "Create activity" dialog appears, here also the "Finish" button is disabled. 
I select "blank activity" from the list box and click next

4) On the fourth step "New blank Activity" dialog box appears as shown in the figure.
```

[image: What to put in the mentioned box]

After entering something in the hierarchical Parent field, the finish button gets activated. After clicking finish the application skeleton is created.

Now, when I run the application, I face either two issues
1) Sometimes it says that there is an error in the project and ask to fix that
2) If it runs, the emulator appears and nothing about the application being run.

I downloaded the apk file and installed in my Samsung Galaxy S2, But the open/run button is disabled there.

Comment: Have you followed all the steps in the android hello world tutorial? http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html

Comment: @mrucci, yes I. But there nothing about the last dialog box i shown in the picture.

Comment: Somebody else had the same problem.  It seems that you have to update eclipse: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11717294/hierarchical-parent-error-when-create-new-android-project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, i met the same problem.I did as other said just checking updates,but nothing was found.Then I reinstalled ADT plugins using https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/,and ADT version was updated from v20.0.0 to v20.0.1.All the problems were solved.

Answer (score 0):

1. Give the name u want in hierarchical Parent feild
2. Go to AndroidManifest.xml need an "android.intent.action.MAIN" for start.

**add**

`action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN`
`category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER`