# "R cannot be resolved to a variable" error

Tags: android, eclipse

I think these posts are the best here on stackoverflow that are related to my issue:

[“R cannot be resolved to a variable”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824730/r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable)

[R cannot be resolved - Android error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error?lq=1)

I tried every answer on those posts, but I still didnt fix my "R cannot be resolved to a variable" error. I'm really desperate at this point. The interesting part is that I had yesterday the same problem and I fixed it with the clean project + restart IDE method, but today it's not working.
I never had this problem until I updated my ADT to ADT 21.1.0.
I know that my res files are not allowed to have any errors, but they have some warnings. Are those warnings coausing the problem?

Comment: check your `manifest` file. Most likely that seems to have gotten affected.

Comment: Have u seen below link :-

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824730/r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable>

Comment: I did, no errors there. Only 2 warnings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`R.java` is deleted whenever there exists any compile error in `res/` folder or in `AndroidManifest.xml` file. You have to check *every* files in `res/` folder *and* `AndroidManifest.xml` to fix the problem.

Comment: I have checked them 3 times now. No errors, only few warnings about Hardcoded string, Should use "sp" instead of "dp" for text sizes,  Missing contentDescription attribute on image, etc.

Comment: @Aksiom It is very common to have absolutely no warnings and no errors and still have problems with "R.java cannot be resolved" problem. I know this can be frustrating, but you have to check line by line.

Comment: Yea i managed to find 2 errors after checking line by line, but that really sucks. I dont even want to imagine what if I had around 100 res files. Thank you for pushing me :)

Comment: Just downloaded FacebookSDK - tried to compile and - “R cannot be resolved to a variable” error. Create new empty project - “R cannot be resolved to a variable” error. even when open old working projects - same error. Te only difference is migrated from WindowsXP to Windows8 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it will happen when memory cache not cleared previous data . Just simply clear your project then it will worked .

procedure :
   In eclipse go project then you will see clear ...

then press clear and select your project and press ok .
 hope it will work. best of luck