# cleaned project now its broken getting import errors

Tags: android, import

i cleaned my android project and now im getting this error saying i need to put `import android.R;` at the top, when i do that it then says that any field isnt visible, for example i have this line of coding

```
setContentView(R.layout.inbox);
```

when i hover over the error mark i get

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Inbox cannot be resolved or is not a field
    - R cannot be resolved to a variable.
```

Im getting this on all of my Activity

UPDATE:

some errors from my XML that is causing the R.java to not be rebuilt durring the cleaning proces

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/friendrowbg'). friendslistselector.xml /atmebeta/res/layout    line 8  Android AAPT Problem
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/friendslistselector').   friend_row.xml  /atmebeta/res/layout    line 1  Android AAPT Problem
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/friendrowbg'). friendslistselector.xml /atmebeta/res/layout    line 2  Android AAPT Problem
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/friendrowbg'). friendslistselector.xml /atmebeta/res/layout    line 6  Android AAPT Problem
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'listSelector' with value '@drawable/friendslistselector'). friends.xml /atmebeta/res/layout    line 29 Android AAPT Problem
```

Comment: Check in your xml file for any errors, save the xml and try again. And dont use `android.R`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not import `android.R`. There is up to a couple minutes (~2) for R.java to be recreated at times.

If R.java is not created then there is a problem within your *res* folder. What helped the OP (found in the comments as well) was the `@drawable` reference is referencing items that are located within *res/drawable/*, not within *res/layout*. The layout folder is only for layout xml files, while the drawable is for your apps images.

Comment: Its just simply `R cannot be resolved to a variable`, and i agree i didnt want to have to and its worked this whole time without it.

Comment: Did you check to see if the clean had finished and recreated your R.java file?

Comment: If you are using Eclipse, on the left side is the Package Explore. Go to your project and expand the gen folder all the way out and you should see two files, one being R.java

Comment: No its not there... wonder what happened to it. How do i fix that?

Comment: Try closing Eclipse, starting and do a clean again.

Comment: Then it seems that there is an error in your XML that is causing R to not build.

Comment: It appears that you deleted your drawable folder, but you are still trying to reference those drawables.

Comment: those files are in my layout folder, they should be in drawable?... there xml files

Comment: Yes, they should be in res/drawable, not res/layout.

Comment: awesome thank you, can you add that into your answer for other people to se later... noob mistake i suppose. I coming from iOS

Comment: Not a problem and sure thing.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check  a similar question posted before:

["R cannot be resolved to a variable"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824730/r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable)

Basically, it seems that it could be an error on an XML or your code that prevents R to be generated again, hence, it's missing. In worst scenario some configuration on your project may be missing or a library project may be causing the issue.

Check that question or provide more information about your set up.

Comment: This kind of makes sense, i just added some list_row.xml files to build a custom ListView...

Comment: Check in the Window > Show View > Problems tab.  Do you see more errors than just the R file ones?

Answer (score 0):

Your project itself will have an R file for your local resources (everything in the /res/ directory).

If your project is com.example.app... add this line

```
import com.example.app.R;
```

Comment: tried this and it just says that that import cant be resolved

Comment: which means that there were issues building your project. Check to make sure everything compiled correctly in eclipse. Once your R file gets generated this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The R file is built automatically when the project is built.  Do you have "Build Automatically" checked (it's under the Project menu)?  If not, doing a Clean will remove the R file, but a Build will not be executed.  You'll need to either select Build, or check the Build Automatically.

You can also go to Window > Show View > Progress and see if a build is in progress.  Doing a Clean should trigger a build if Build Automatically is checked.

Comment: Build Automatically is checked, i did uncheck it earlier and clean to see if that would fix it and it didnt.

Comment: Did you try manually doing a build?  Does the Progress window show the build process?