# Failed to load jni shared library jvm.dll and R cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I am a beginner in Android Development. I'm encountering lots of problems while starting to configure the IDE. I have downloaded the full SDK from [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download). Since I have Windows 64-bit version I have selected 64-bit. I have extracted it, the website says all the files are preloaded and there is nothing more to download.

When opening Eclipse I get the error `failed to load jni shared library jvm.dll eclipse`.

I downloaded some other versions of Eclipse it runs and I have installed Android Developer tools in it and specified the SDK location of the previous archive. This version of Eclipse Shows the Error `r cannot be resolved to a variable`, intact the `R.java file` is not generated.

I'm fed up, could someone throw some light onto this situation?

Comment: Is your Eclipse 64bit?

Comment: I have downloaded the full SDK Which was specified as 64 bit.There are two options 32 and 64 see the link i have provided

Comment: And your Java is 64bit as well?

Comment: I had downloaded 64bit JVM(Java 7) still does not work.The java is located in Program Files Folder (Java 7) and the Program Files(X86) contains the old java(java6).Now i have uninstalled Java 7 but same problem before and after

Comment: `Right Click` on your Project > `Properties` > `Java Compiler` and check which JDK it's pointing to.

Comment: @SamRad Went there,there is no Path there

Comment: So your Eclipse is not recognizing your JDK. Watch [How to change JRE / JDK in Eclipse project](http://youtu.be/S5xeXawYgK0). It may help.

Comment: @SamRad Checked it but in my eclipse in the Java Built path,there is no JRE system Library shown

Comment: Add it. `Windows` > `Preferences` > `Java` > `Installed JRE` > `Add`.

Comment: Then I don't know anything else. But read this before you give up: [R cannot be resolved to a variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7824730/1693859)

Comment: I did nothing. But I'm pretty sure it's an easy thing. Good Luck ;)