# I've tried everything and still can't solve the "R cannot be resolved to a variable" message

Tags: android, build

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

gives me the error message in the title. I've tried to delete and renerate R, clean the project and nothing. activity_main is right there registered in R. I have no problems in /res, no red crosses or problems in the problems tab. There's no import android.R in my Activity.
I've tried everything I could find here and nothing.
["R cannot be resolved to a variable"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824730/r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable)

What's going on?

Comment: Is the activity in the same package as what you declared in the `package` attribute in your manifest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest coding pattern, and what you will see most examples do, is to have the activities (and any other resource-dependent classes) reside in the Java package declared in the manifest's `package` attribute. That way, `R` is auto-imported, and you don't have to think about it.

You are welcome to have `R` references in other packages, but you will have to import the `R` from the manifest's `package` (e.g., `import com.commonsware.sample.R;`).

Comment: And you still went further and probably prevented a future episode of me for 30 minutes asking myself where the mistake is. Thanks again for this :)