# Still having trouble with .R after installing ADT

Tags: java, eclipse, adt

I've spent the past 2-3 hours today and yesterday looking for a reason why ADT won't generate my R.java file. I've gone through cleaning, making sure SDK versions match up, making sure I have everything updated, and checking over my XML files.

The XML files don't have any obvious errors, but I could be wrong. Haven't touched Java in years :)

**Note that this is a completely brand new install** of ADT, and the error appears immediately after I start a new project, before I even change anything. I've tried this on 2 PCs to eliminate some weird path problems on my work PC. Nothing still.

I've gone through all the tips in here, for example: ["R cannot be resolved to a variable"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824730/r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable)

Comment: I just moved to Eclipse:Kepler yesterday, didn't have any major problems. Unpacked Eclipse, ran it, went to the marketplace and installed ADT, imported projects from Juno. What's the error?

Comment: I did the ADT bundle (http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), unpacked, ran the SDK manager to get that loaded, copied eclipse to another folder, and ran it. Upon making a new project, MainActivity opens, and shows 'R cannot be resolved to a variable' errors on lines 12 and 19: 

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

Comment: [It says here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/bundle.html) not to move the eclipse files, if you do, you'll have to update some preferences - not the end of the world, but they don't detail which preferences to update. (see the Caution)

Comment: HOLY CRAP that did it! Works perfectly now, builds the .R!

Thanks for your help - appreciate it.