# android - eclipse - R cannot be resolved to a variable ERROR

Tags: android, eclipse, variables, r.java-file

I'm getting a strange error eclipse says "R cannot be resolved to a variable"

I don't know wath to do.

Do i have to poste my Manifest file?
My xml file?

I have tryed :
    clean project
    update AVD
    update SDK

this is my code:

```
//package

//imports

 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

public Handler timer = new Handler();

public int counter = 0;

 //vars

TextView mTextView;
ImageButton finishhimbutton;
ImageButton resetbutton;

 //images

public ImageView jb1;
public ImageView jb2;
public ImageView jb3;
public ImageView jb4;
public ImageView jb5;
public ImageView jb6;
    TextView txtCount;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//define

        txtCount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timer);              
        txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
        jb1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.JB1);
        jb2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.JB2);
        jb3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.JB3);
        jb4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.JB4);
        jb5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.JB5);
        jb6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.JB6);

 //click button
        finishhimbutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.finishhim);
        resetbutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.reserbutton);
        timer = new Handler();


        final Runnable hMyTimeTask = new Runnable() {
               public void run() {

                    if (counter < 49) {

                    counter = 0;
                    txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
                    jb1.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
                    jb2.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb3.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb4.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb5.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb6.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    }

                   else if (counter > 50) {     
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "WINNER", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
               }

            }; 



        finishhimbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (counter == 1) {
                    timer.removeCallbacks(hMyTimeTask);
                    timer.postDelayed(hMyTimeTask, 4000);
                 }

           switch(counter){

     //case's

           case 1:
                    counter++;
                    txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
                    jb1.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
                    jb2.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb3.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb4.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb5.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb6.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    break;

                        //................and more case's
                                //there are more case's


                }

                }


}

);

    //reset button

resetbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            counter = 0;
            txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
            jb1.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
            jb2.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
            jb3.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
            jb4.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
            jb5.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
            jb6.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
              Intent screen = new Intent(MainActivity.this, startscreen.class);
              MainActivity.this.startActivity(screen);
        }
    });
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}
}
```

Comment: do you have import android.R;. Any errors in resource files

Comment: check if you have import android.R instead of your project's R class

Comment: if i import android.r; i get error's on R.layout.activity_main  <----

Comment: Look in your project's gen folder. Is R.java in there? If not, you most likely have an error in one of your layout xml files.

Comment: How is your R import? is it the package name?

Comment: the R import is import android.R;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check if you import android.R and check your xmls for errors
and also rebuild all project

Comment: if i import android.r; i get error's on R.layout.activity_main <---- –

Comment: check activity_main.xml exist in layout and look inside maybe in this file you make some error

Comment: But also R.id.timer and more

Comment: @CaptainStony remove  `import android.R;`. R.java will not be generated if you have errors in your resource files

Comment: I have removed android.R; and now the file is not generating

Comment: Did you see any errors now ? What are those ? If no errors seen, try to do Project --> Clean as a first step and notice if any errors come up and comment back

Answer (score 1):

1. close Eclipse and open your Workspace directory.
2. look for a folder named ".metadata" and **delete** that folder.

the Error should go away :)

Answer (score 0):

1.Remove `import android.R;` and your main project import.

2.Then go to the error variable and import your project reference.

Comment: Sorry i don't know wath you mean

Comment: actually there will be an import of android.R in your MainActivity class...First remove this.

Comment: also remove your main project import

Comment: after that go to any variable and import your main project refrence like <com.example.test>

Comment: Sorry but how do i do that?

Comment: go to this line in your code. jb1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.JB1);

Comment: and hover on R.id.JB1 ,it will display the available import then import your main project reference(your main package name).

Comment: When i hover on it it says to change the name

Comment: Can you give me an example please?

Comment: But the R.java is missing do you know how to generate it?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you search Stack Overflow before opening a new report.

This will help :

["R cannot be resolved to a variable"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824730/r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable)

Comment: I don't get it i know the problem but I don't know how to solve it the problem is : R.java don't generate

Comment: As others have said, this is a very common problem which arises when you make a mistake in your program. For example, it might be an error in one of your xml file. Most Android programmers encounter this from time to time and you should look at the link I provided.