# error: package R does not exist how to debug when using command line

Tags: android, ant, command-line

I am Managing Projects from the Command Line and I got this error 
error: package R does not exist on setContentView

I am having a hard time to figure out what went wrong any ideas how to debug this?
(I am not using eclipse)

Comment: Double check ALL of your xml files. make sure that no file contains a capital letter. Project/Clean. File/Restart.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["R cannot be resolved to a variable"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824730/r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R is generated automatically. Check your resource files, and try building the project. 
Also, try `ant clean`