# Android R Cannot Be Resolved to Variable - Changing Package Name

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I've seen a lot of threads discussing when R cannot be resolved to a variable.  I tried the solutions that can be found here: ["R cannot be resolved to a variable"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824730/r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable).

None of them worked.  I think I have found my problem, but I don't know the fix.

My `src` package name is `seniordesign.mobileapp` and the package in `gen` that contains `R.java` is `com.example.android.BluetoothChat`

This seems like it is my problem, how do I rename the package in `gen` or otherwise point to `com.example.android.BluetoothChat` in my code?

I am using the latest version of Eclipse and both `R.java` and `BuildConfig.java` can be found in my `gen` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In manifest.xml also rename the package at the manifest tag

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="old.package.name"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
```

to

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="new.package.name"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
```