# Android crashed - No resource identifier found for attribute

Tags: android

I am becoming desperate. My Android Studio crashed and now I cant build my app anymore. It gives me Error Code 1 and saying that no resource identifier found for attribute.
Any idea how I can fix it again? I tried google but nothing helped so far. Also rerun Gradle, reboot the PC .... nothing so far :(

```
:app:processDebugResources
C:\Users\stephan\Google Drive\AndroidStudioProjects\HobbyAthletes\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_home.xml
Error:(27) No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_toEndOf' in package 'android'
Error:(45) No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_alignEnd' in package 'android'
Error:(54) No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_alignStart' in package 'android'
Error:(64) No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_alignParentEnd' in package 'android'
Error:(75) No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_alignParentStart' in package 'android'
C:\Users\stephan\Google Drive\AndroidStudioProjects\HobbyAthletes\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_login.xml
Error:(192) No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_alignParentStart' in package 'android'
C:\Users\stephan\Google Drive\AndroidStudioProjects\HobbyAthletes\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_myeventref.xml
    Error:(45) No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_alignParentStart' in package 'android'
```

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       C:\Users\stephan\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W\aapt.exe package -f --no-crunch -I C:\Users\stephan\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\platforms\android-16\android.jar -M C:\Users\stephan\Google Drive\AndroidStudioProjects\HobbyAthletes\app\build\intermediates\manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Users\stephan\Google Drive\AndroidStudioProjects\HobbyAthletes\app\build\intermediates\res\debug -A C:\Users\stephan\Google Drive\AndroidStudioProjects\HobbyAthletes\app\build\intermediates\assets\debug -m -J C:\Users\stephan\Google Drive\AndroidStudioProjects\HobbyAthletes\app\build\generated\source\r\debug -F C:\Users\stephan\Google Drive\AndroidStudioProjects\HobbyAthletes\app\build\intermediates\libs\app-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package com.hobbyathletes.hobbyathletes -0 apk --output-text-symbols C:\Users\stephan\Google Drive\AndroidStudioProjects\HobbyAthletes\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug
>   Error Code:
>       1
>   Output:
>       C:\Users\stephan\Google Drive\AndroidStudioProjects\HobbyAthletes\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\layout\activity_home.xml:27: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_toEndOf' in package 'android'
>       C:\Users\stephan\Google Drive\AndroidStudioProjects\HobbyAthletes\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\layout\activity_home.xml:45: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_alignEnd' in package 'android'
>       C:\Users\stephan\Google Drive\AndroidStudioProjects\HobbyAthletes\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\layout\activity_home.xml:54: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_alignStart' in package 'android'
>       C:\Users\stephan\Google Drive\AndroidStudioProjects\HobbyAthletes\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\layout\activity_home.xml:64: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_alignParentEnd' in package 'android'
>       C:\Users\stephan\Google Drive\AndroidStudioProjects\HobbyAthletes\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\layout\activity_home.xml:75: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_alignParentStart' in package 'android'
>       C:\Users\stephan\Google Drive\AndroidStudioProjects\HobbyAthletes\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\layout\activity_login.xml:192: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_alignParentStart' in package 'android'
>       C:\Users\stephan\Google Drive\AndroidStudioProjects\HobbyAthletes\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\layout\activity_myeventref.xml:45: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_alignParentStart' in package 'android'
>       C:\Users\stephan\Google Drive\AndroidStudioProjects\HobbyAthletes\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\layout\activity_myeventref.xml:126: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_alignParentStart' in package 'android'
>       C:\Users\stephan\Google Drive\AndroidStudioProjects\HobbyAthletes\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\layout\activity_myeventref.xml:141: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_alignParentStart' in package 'android'
>    `$`

Comment: Post your `activity_home.xml`.

Comment: Dont know how to respond here... http://codeviewer.org/view/code:45aa I also have the problem in the java classes that R. cant be resolved...

Comment: possible duplicate of ["R cannot be resolved to a variable"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824730/r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable)

Comment: yes check whether there is more than 1 R.java file inside "gen" folder.....the id was not set on R.java...there comes few cases...case 1. R.java does not exist... case 2. Possible duplicate of R.java and the duplicate doesn;t contain the id case 3.you're missing the resource value inside all that attributes

Comment: Does it help, when I say I have to gen folder and I am also not sure if I ever had one? Why had my PC to crash...

Comment: Ok, I solved it by using an old version of my project and replaced it with my latest java and layout files. Of course I had to add my dependencies but at least its running again