# R cannot be resolved to a variable and multiple markers at this line

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

i have problem. i will try to make maps, but when in onCreate i have problem. i have two problem.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SupportMapFragment fragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mGoogleMap = fragment.getMap();

    handleIntent(getIntent());
```

i have two problem

in `setContenView(R.Layout.activity_main)`

the problem is `R cannot be resolved to a variable`

in `SupportMapFragment fragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);`

the problem is

> Multiple markers at this line
>
> SupportMapFragment cannot be resolved 
>        to a type
>
> map cannot be resolved or is not a field
>
> SupportMapFragment cannot be resolved 
>        to a type

please help me,

thanx

Comment: Any problem related to R means there is some error in any xml file of yours. Try and check all the xml files for any error is possible. Also , check for imports and project libraries (if any)
Sometimes, the xml doesnt shows error, so you may have to go line by line to check for errors that may have risen accidentally.

Comment: are all your xml in res folder error free??

Comment: for the @Panther just one file, but that's not eror, that's alert. so how?

Comment: wats the alert, also check the package name in `AndroidManifest.xml` and your `java` file. Both must be same :-/

Comment: for @AtishAgrawal so, i must look at line by line for the folder and file in res?? when i try to import package R, there is problem again. so i get confused. why my project

Comment: my package in AndroidManifest.xml like here `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationsherlocksearchviewmapv2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
` and code in MainActivity.java like this `package in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationsherlocksearchviewmapv2;
`

Comment: u r ide and build system?

Comment: what it's ride?? ride it's write?? yes i want make a systems the system is about navigation traffic. this system for my thesis

Comment: wats ur `IDE` and `build system` u r using ??. Try to clean and rebuild the project.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["R cannot be resolved to a variable"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824730/r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable)

Comment: @Panther how to clean and rebuild the project, whether to refresh project? my IDE is eclipse, an i build a system android.

Comment: what's your main about possibla duplicate, i not understand @Funkystein

Comment: Check the linked post

Comment: if you can use teamviewer or something for remote access...i may help

Answer (score 0):

```
package testMail;

public class testMail {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
        String hostname="smtp.example.com";
        int port=2525;
        String username="nawale.pandu@gmail.com";
        String password="kskcpz09";
        Mailer mailer=new Mailer(hostname,port,username,password);
        /* error  
    Multiple markers at this line
    - Mailer cannot be resolved 
     to a type
    - Mailer cannot be resolved 
     to a type */
    }

}
```