# Android cannot resolve R

Tags: android, xml, r.java-file

This happened yesterday when i was replacing a few elements in my XML. When I went to my main class, I saw that all references to R had been marked red, and I was told that R could not be resolved to a variable. At first, I tried to rebuild and clean up my project, but that didn't work, so I am assuming that the issue lies in the XML file I recently edited, however I do now know where the issue would lie. And yes, I did make sure android.R was not being imported.

A few additional details:

- I am using Android 5.0 (API 21)
- The R issues do not appear in my other class files, which reference R.

Here is the XML file in question:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/rye"
        android:textColor="#888888"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge" />

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:isIndicator="false"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:stepSize="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dropDownButton"
        android:layout_width="48dip"
        android:layout_height="48dip"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ratingBar1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ratingBar1"
        android:onClick="dropDown"
        android:text=">"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/dropDownLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/testTV"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Testing dropdown" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/tipTitle"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#888888"
        android:layout_below="@+id/quizFragment"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/quizFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/dropDownButton" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/people_dining_title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#888888"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seekBar3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subtotalTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/subtotal"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#888888"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seekBar2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/seekBar2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/seekBar2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/totalTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/subtotalText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/subtotalText"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/total"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#888888" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/totalText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/subtotalText"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/subtotalText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/totalTitle"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#ffff000c" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/subtotalText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/subtotalTitle"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="SUBTOTAL"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/seekBar2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/seekBar2">
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/eppTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/totalText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/totalText"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/epp"
        android:textColor="#888888"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/eppText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/eppTitle"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/totalText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/eppTitle"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonDone"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/eppText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:onClick="done"
        android:text="@string/done"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/seekBar3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This happens to me sometimes too in Eclipse (are you using that?) and I usually end up raging and create a new project from scratch and just import all the .java and .xml files. I am commenting so I can look at this later if someone has a solution to the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["R cannot be resolved to a variable"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824730/r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable)

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to see any issues in this xml file . Can you also post the code for the class file where you are using it and check if you're not using `android.r` and using `com.yourapp.r` . This might be the case. Could you post the class also

Comment: As I went to reopen the project and the class file to show you, I tried importing the class R again (it wouldn't even show up before) and it showed up and everything seems to be fixed!

Comment: Yup it probably worked the import Happy to help ;) Mark & upvote if this was useful

Comment: Happens with me all the time we copy a Lot :D