# R cannot be resolved to a variable ---

Tags: java, android, eclipse, r.java-file

I know this question had been asked many times, and I tried everything to make it go away, but the error is still here.. I tried all these: ["R cannot be resolved to a variable"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824730/r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable) but the error won't disappear. Maybe it has something to do with the appcompat_v7 I deleted? I don't know exactly what files I should post to solve this problem.

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.testjk.MainActivity" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/PlayArea"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >




            <Button
                android:id="@+id/eleven"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:text="@string/eleven" />
     //some more here

    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">testjk</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="turn_human">Jouw beurt.</string>


    //some more here
</resources>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.testjk;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.example.testjk.R;
```

TicTacToeGame.java = in same folder as MainActivity = com.example.

```
package com.example.testjk;

import java.util.Random;
```

Comment: That error is a side-effect of some other error in a resource or your manifest. Look for the error indicators on those items in the Package Explorer in Eclipse, or look at the Errors view to see what is wrong with those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this error occurs when some xml file under /res folder have some issues or you have some errors in your manifest file. see error log on eclipse to find the real problem.