# Eclipse Will Not Generate R.Java In Linux

Tags: java, android, linux, eclipse

as stated in the title. I can not get Eclipse to generate an R.java file. It fails immediately after the creation of the project. I have read around and fixes have been stated as such:

1. Clean Project
2. fix android project
3. make sure all res/ files are lower case
4. make sure xml files are clean and no errors
5. make sure Build Tools is installed

Well I have tried everything for 3 days now and i can't get anything to work. I have even gone as far as marking every file in my android-sdk as "executable". Nothing works for me. Mind you I have never had this problem on my windows 7 machine. I am fairly new to android development.

I have attached images. First one is a screen shot showing that I do have all build tools and up Second is a Screen shot showing the errors and directory tree within my project. As you can see the only errors output are those that point to R.Java File

edit: I can't upload images so I have provided links to the screenshots within my Google Drive

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B73rHBl5RuotOTUtQURfUTdveW8&usp=sharing

Comment: Possible duplicate from [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error) ?

Comment: Is there any output from Eclipse error console?

Comment: It says aapt error and fails. I'm sorry I am not near my computer at the moment so no screen shot available

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a duplicate for this one:

["R cannot be resolved to a variable"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824730/r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable)

It has been extensively responded.

Comment: I realize this question has been asked but as I stated none of the fixes worked for me.

Comment: One of the good answers about this is the following: Everytime you have the problem of the R file not being generated is because you have a problem in your XML layout file that prevents the application from being built. That's why cleaning the project doesn't work. You have to try detect what you have wrong in your XML and fix that.

Comment: One thing I'm seeing now is you named your project with a dot (.) in its name: Speed.cd  . I'm wondering if this could be affecting the Android build. Eclipse usually treats the dot internally as a directory separator. Wondering if that could be interfering.

Comment: I also created as project named speed and another named test to to test that theory mark. It happened then as well. I'm not sure why anything would have been wrong in any file though because this is all happening at creation. I haven't edited anything. Thanks for helping I hope this gets solved soon.