# R cannot be resolved to a variable Eclipse for Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

package com.proappangeloooo1.game1;

import com.proappangeloooo1.game1.R;

/* the error :R cannot be resolved to a variable*/

Comment: This is typically caused by an error in your *res* folder.  For example, one of your layout XML files may be referencing a non-existent string.

Answer (score 0):

You should not explicitly import R at the top of your java code. Try making Project -> Clean...

Comment: "You should not import R" => of course you should, how else are you going to get access to the app resources from the java code ?

Comment: I thought you don't need to import R on Eclipse with Android development plugin. I don't need explicit import of R in my projects. Also, [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7824871/3460040) states you should not import R

Comment: I don't know about the necessity to explicitely import R in the code, you must be right about not needing it. But the error is linked to R not being generated, not because of the import, IMO.

Comment: Edited my answer to eliminate misunderstanding

Comment: explicitly import R class only when R class and the classes which use R are not in the same package.

Comment: I thought it's necessary to import the Class R I test the same code in another pc it works