# Android external library R class not loading

Tags: android, android-library

I recently added the expandable-menu-button which i got from [github](https://github.com/lemonlabs/ExpandableButtonMenu) and the .jar library from  [search.maven.org](http://search.maven.org)  to my android project but when i try to build and run the project, i get the error below:

```
E:\xdroid\appname\libs\expandable-button-menu-1.0.0-sources.jar(lt/lemonlabs/android/expandablebuttonmenu/ExpandableMenuOverlay.java):56: error: package R does not exist
        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ExpandableMenuOverlay, 0, 0);
                                                                         ^
E:\xdroid\appname\libs\expandable-button-menu-1.0.0-sources.jar(lt/lemonlabs/android/expandablebuttonmenu/ExpandableMenuOverlay.java):58: error: package R does not exist
            mAdjustViewSize = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.ExpandableMenuOverlay_adjustViewSize, true);
                                            ^
E:\xdroid\appname\libs\expandable-button-menu-1.0.0-sources.jar(lt/lemonlabs/android/expandablebuttonmenu/ExpandableMenuOverlay.java):59: error: package R does not exist
            dimAmount = a.getFloat(R.styleable.ExpandableMenuOverlay_dimAmount, DEFAULT_DIM_AMOUNT);
```

What am I doing wrong such that the R.java file is unavailable and how can i correct it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: how you added the library ? was it through gradle or manually?

Comment: Exactly the same ways i have added other libraries...first I copy the .jar file to the libs folder then on android studio I right click on the .jar file and add it as a library

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["R cannot be resolved to a variable"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824730/r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable)

Comment: I do not think it is a duplicate because this library makes calls from a different package name i.e. `lt.lemonlabs.android.expandablebuttonmenu` which is different from my package name and thus cannot access the default R.java file

Comment: you are still using eclipse?

Comment: No, I use android studio. I have used that process on 4 other libraries and I did not have any issues