# ant copying android project -> not compiling 'error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_width' with value 'match_parent'). '

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, ant

I splitted a phonegap app into a base part, an android specific part and and ios specific part. I wrote an ant script that re-assembles the code, depending on which platform I want to build for.
The Ant Script copies the android project and adds specific file to the assets/www directories

When I do a

```
./android update project --target 1 --path /workspace/projectroot
```

and then

```
ant debug
```

from the project`s root directory I get the following error

```
'error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_width' with value 'match_parent'). '
BUILD FAILED
null returned: 1
```

I open the new assembled project in eclipse,  and see a problem: the android.jar and the Android Dependencies is not there, comparing it to my source Project.

So how can I fix this? Any ideas?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you check what target do you have with id=1 (--target 1)? Just call `android list targets`

Most probably you use wrong API level. Check answer here [Android NDK r4 san-angeles problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000131/android-ndk-r4-san-angeles-problem)

Comment: you saved my day and my weekend! I changed it from 1 to 4, which is mapped to sdk level 8